# Run a Macro in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

i have a question about access 2000 or 2003 , i need to make a macro that opens the form and automatically clicks a button that runs a query , how can i do this, may some example can help me to do this ? any suggestions ? my idea is to run something like this:

```
Sub Refreshfiledata()
m  = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to run this macro ?.", vbYesNo)
If m = 6 Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SendKeys "{Enter}"
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      MsgBox "Done"
  End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: I've removed the `tsql` tag as irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendkeys is almost never a solution to anything.

You could put something like this in a module:

```
Sub OpenAForm()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
    Forms!Form1.cmdClick_Click
End Sub
```

Which would refer to this code on form1, note that the word `Private` that Access usually adds before Sub has been deleted:

```
Sub cmdClick_Click()
    ''For a query to display data
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"
    ''For a query to change data
    CurrentDB.Execute "Query1", dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

You would have to alter the code to suit your set-up.

Comment: You posted VBA, so I thought you were using VBA, which is what you have above. Only the first sub is really relevant, the second sub shows what the code on your form might look like. What *does* the code on your form look like? Do you have any code?

Comment: i thought that it is like the code i posted , but now i am working in macro and where in macro i have  to put this code?

Comment: You can change the example to a function and call the function from a macro. I never use macros. They are too limited.